# Wanting to return index of first Responder in swift when tapped but order is weird

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have 100 `UITextField` boxes in `storyBoard` which are stored in an array called boxArray.

I also have another array called importantIndexes, which stores important indexes of boxArray.

(Bear with me on this on this next paragraph)

When a user taps on a specific `UITextField` box in boxArray who's index matches a value in the importantIndexes array. I then want to return the index of importantIndexes array which value is the index of the boxArray first responder.

This is the function that gets called when one of the specific `UITextField` are tapped:

```
@objc func myNotWorkingFunction(textField: UITextField) {
    for i in 0...99 {
        if (boxArray[i]?.isFirstResponder)! {
            let index = boxArray.index(of: boxArray[i])
            print(index)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running into two problems. The first is that the print function is returning "Optional(Index)". I just want the int value Index but it's printing it like this example: Optional(14).

My second problem is that this seems to print the index of first responder of whatever was the first responder before it was changed to the new one. Let's say the user was at 11th boxArray `UITextField`, then taps on the 55th, the print returns "Optional(11)" instead of just "55" which is what I want.

I can't use `textFieldDidEndEditing(:_)` here, which would probably work fine. I have to stick with the tapping functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: just edit this `print(index)` to  `print(index ?? 0)` or use `if let` or `guard`

Comment: I think you need to return i directly instead of indexOf

Answer (score 0):

First problem is solved by unwrapping

```
if let index = boxArray.index(of: boxArray[i]) {
    print(index)
}
```

Second problem 'may' be that you need to call this when your `objc function` is called.

declare:
`var currentTextField: UITextField?`

In your function:

```
    currentTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
    currentTextField = textField
    textField.becomesFirstResponder()
```

Comment: This worked however my keyboard hides for some reason when I do this, quite unexpected.

Comment: are you calling `resignFirstResponder()` elsewhere on a `textField delegate` method?

Comment: Never called resignFirstResponder() anywhere, the function now looks the same except I added your changes and the new line textField.becomeFirstResponder() before the for loop

Comment: Still having the same issue, I'm completely baffled. I did notice however if I hold down the tap, the keyboard remains. But once I let it go it disappears. Could it be the tapping action doing it automatically when it ends? Hmm... The keyboard does not hide at all if I take out the becomeFirstResponder() line

Comment: Are you running this on a real device, or in simulator ?

Comment: I'm running on a simulator, the keyboard doesn't hide if I take out the becomeFirstResponder() line

Comment: Strange!  Could try it on a real device.  Sometimes the simulator gives unexpected behaviour.  Sorry I can't help you further.  If you still can't solve it, you may need to post your whole Class so we can figure out whats going on.

Comment: For the sake of testing, in my viewDidLoad function I just assigned a random box to the first responder and the keyboard did show up when I launched the app. But within the objective c function it's as if the keyboard tries to show up and then is forced to hide when the function finishes.

Comment: you could try putting the three lines above into the delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.  You would need to set the delegate on each of the textFields though.